# (RGBData on Haskell) Pattern match failure

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, rgb

im new using Haskell, im doing a proyect and i got some doubts with data types.

im working with PBM files and im using this data types

```
data RGBdata= RGB Int Int Int
data PBMfile= PBM Int Int [[RGBdata]]
```

also this code that the teacher gave to us

```
instance Show RGBdata where
show (RGB r g b)=(show r)++" "++(show g)++" "++(show b)
instance Show PBMfile where
show (PBM width height l)= "P3\n"++(show width)++" "++(show height)++"\n255\n"++(foldr    (++) "" (map myshow l))
myshow [] = "\n"
myshow (h:t) = (show h)++" "++(myshow t)
cargarPBM name = readFile name >>= return . rLines . lines 
rLines (_:x:_:xs)= (\[a,b] -> (PBM (read a) (read b) (rLines' (read a) (concat $map     words xs)))) $ words x
rLines' _ [] = []
rLines' a x = (rLine (take (a*3) x): rLines' a (drop (a*3) x))
rLine []= []
rLine (r:g:b:xs)= ((RGB (read r) (read g) (read b)):rLine xs)
aplicar funcion origen destino= cargarPBM origen >>= writeFile destino . show . funcion
```

Then i need to do some functions with the PBM files, like transform it to negative, rotate it, etc..
im starting making the PBM negative, to transform to negative is (RGB 255-R 255-G 255-B)

i did a function to make a PBMfile negative! here is the code i did..

```
negativo :: PBMfile -> PBMfile
negativo (PBM i j mtx) = (PBM i j (aplicar_negativo 0 (i*j) mtx)) 

aplicar_negativo :: Int -> Int -> [[RGBdata]] -> [[RGBdata]]
aplicar_negativo a n (x:xs) | ((a+2)==n) = (aplicar_negativo2 [x])++(aplicar_negativo2 xs)
                        | otherwise = (aplicar_negativo2 [x])++(aplicar_negativo (a+1) n xs)

aplicar_negativo2 :: [[RGBdata]] -> [[RGBdata]]
aplicar_negativo2 [[RGB x y z]] = ([[RGB (255-x) (255-y) (255-z)]])
```

**this 3 functions just change all rgbdatas to 255-r, 255-g and 255-b.. 
ie if i have my list of lists [[RGB 100 200 100],[RGB 50 55 50]]
the result is: [[RGB 155 55 155],[RGB 205, 200, 205]]**

**And here is the error that i get when i apply the function negativo over a image:**

```
Program error: pattern match failure: aplicar_negativo2 [[RGB (read (_SEL (,) 
("6" ++ _SEL (,) ("5" ++ _SEL (,) ([],[]) 1,[]) 1,[]) 1)) (read (_SEL (,) ("1"
++ _SEL (,) ("2" ++ _SEL (,) ("6" ++ _SEL (,) ([],[]) 1,[]) 1,[]) 1,[]) 1)) 
(read (_SEL (,) ("7" ++ _SEL (,) ("1" ++ _SEL (,) ([],[]) 1,[]) 1,[]) 1)),RGB 
(read (_SEL (,) ("5" ++ _SEL (,) ("2" ++ _SEL (,) ([],[]) 1,[]) 1,[]) 1)) (read
(_SEL (,) ("1" ++ _SEL (,) ("1" ++ _SEL (,) ("2" ++ _SEL (,) ([],[]) 1,[]) 1,[])
1,[]) 1)) (read (_SEL (,) (words_v858 (break isSpace "5" ++ _SEL (,) (span_v848 
(span (not . primEqChar '\n') (_hreader {handle}))) 1)) 1))] ++ rLine (take 
(700 - 1) (words (_SEL (,) (words_v858 (break isSpace "5" ++ _SEL (,) (span_v848 
(span (not . primEqChar '\n') (_hreader {handle}))) 1)) 2) ++ foldr (++) [] 
(map_v810 words (lines_v853 (_SEL (,) ("5" ++ _SEL (,) (span_v848 (span (not .
primEqChar '\n') (_hreader {handle}))) 1,_SEL (,) (span_v848 (span (not . 
primEqChar '\n') (_hreader {handle}))) 2) 2)))))]
```

**Excuse me for my bad english, Thanks!**

Answer (score 1):

The following function:

```
aplicar_negativo2 :: [[RGBdata]] -> [[RGBdata]]
aplicar_negativo2 [[RGB x y z]] = ([[RGB (255-x) (255-y) (255-z)]])
```

only matches a single RGBdata item, in a list, in a list....

However, after looking at the error message (....it wasn't easy, trust me), I was able to see that you called this function with something of the form

```
[[RGB _ _ _,RGB _ _ _] ++ <more stuff>]
```

So you passed something with at least two elements in the inner list, into a function that will only take one element in that list.

My guess is that you meant the logic in `aplicar_negativo2` to apply to all elements inside....  You can do this by defining the function to apply to one element, then using `map` outside (where you use it).

Comment: Sorry, i was inactive, i dont understand your suggest, i work with a [[RGBdata]] i tried with a image little than first.. here is the result!! 

    aplicar negativo "Prueba.pbm" "resnegativo2.pbm"

    **Program error: pattern match failure: rLines_v1623 (lines_v853     (_SEL (,) (lines_v852 (break ('\n' ==) "\ENQ" ++ _hreader {handle})) 2)) [_SEL (,) ("\ENQ" ++ _SEL (,) ("\EOT" ++ _SEL (,) ([],[]) 1,[]) 1,[]) 1]**